# Progressbar rounding to nearest integer - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar, decimal

I am having an issue with progress bars and can't seem to get them to show decimal values such as 0.5 or 4.1. When i set them as values with decimals it says "Property value is not valid". It further says that "2.5 is not a valid value for Int32". Can't seem to find any solutions on these forums or anywhere else on the internet.

Thanks

EDIT : So there is no way for me to assign decimal values in a progress bar?

Comment: No - the value property is `Int32` see answers below to work around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't use decimals in a progress bar.
I suggest you to multiply your value x10 times and set 5 for 0.5 and 41 for 4.1

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the value as an Integer. So if you want to show 0-100% with 0.1% increments you can just scale everything up by 10:

`ProgressBar1.Max = 1000`

Then scale up the value by a factor of 10. So to show 4.1%:

`ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(4.1 * 10)`

If you want to have another digit of precision you could scale up further.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `ProgressBar` class is Defined as integer, so you cannot assign decimal values to it.

```
<BindableAttribute(True)> _
Public Property Value As Integer
```

If you want to show the progress percentage in decimal format, then you can place a label over it and print the value in that label.